# "Undefined attribute name (xmlns)" error in Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Here is the beginning of my HTML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">
    (...)
</html>
```

Whether there is the `<?xml ... ?>` part or not, Eclipse returns me a warning event on the **line 3**

> Undefined attribute name (xmlns).

This `xmlns` attribute is required for correct validation, and so I don't understand why Eclipse returns a warning.

Furthermore, I'm using *Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2* with the last PHP Developer Tool from the Eclipse database.

Anybody know how to remove this warning, or find a way to skip this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is bug filed for similar case here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313859

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr">
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>The content of the document.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Should validated.  Validates fine in Eclipse Juno and here: http://validator.w3.org.